# How to execute multiple select queries in a single query and still retrieve the values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

So I have a bunch of these in my php script:

```
//get current values to add to new ones
    $sql = "SELECT `pageViews` FROM $table WHERE `appName` = '$appName'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
     die("Invalid query: " .mysql_error());
    }
    $totalPoints += mysql_result($result, 0, 0);


    //get current values to add to new ones
    $sql = "SELECT `appTime` FROM $table WHERE `appName` = '$appName'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
     die("Invalid query: " .mysql_error());
    }
    $appRunTime += mysql_result($result, 0, 0);

    //get current values to add to new ones
    $sql = "SELECT `soundsPlayed` FROM $table WHERE `appName` = '$appName'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
     die("Invalid query: " .mysql_error());
    }
    $lifesLost += mysql_result($result, 0, 0);
```

Is it possible to combine all those queries into one and still retrieve each individual information, ie setting them to a variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```php
$sql = "SELECT pageViews, appTime, soundsPlayed 
          FROM $table 
         WHERE appName = '$appName'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
 die("Invalid query: " .mysql_error());
}
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $totalPoints += $row['pageViews'];
    $appRunTime  += $row['appTime'];
    $lifesLost   += $row['soundsPlayed'];
}
```

**On a side note:** instead of interpolating query strings use **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** with either [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: For some reason if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { is always returning false, not sure why but this is what I was wanting, thanks!